# ASP.NET MVC 3 Data Annotation: Add validation dynamically

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, data-annotations

I'm new with data annotation. I'd like to know if it possible (and how) to add some validation dynamically. It is very extensive to explain why, but I've a ViewModel that receives and object when created. In that object I must check for some property and depending its value I should have or not some validations.

An example:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Client Code")]
    public int ClientCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must have up to 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must have up to 50 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must have up to 50 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ProfileViewModel(User usr)
    {
        if (usuario.ClientCode != null)
        {
            ClientCode = Convert.ToInt32(usr.ClientCode);
        }
        else
        {
             //ClientCode and Company are not yet required.
             //Name and LastName are now required.
        }
        Company = usr.Company;
        Name = usr.Name;
        LastName = usr.LastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the simplest way of doing what I wanted is implementing [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class Product : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Prop1 < Prop2)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Property 1 can't be less than Property 2");
    }
}
```

See also: [Class-Level Model Validation with ... ASP.NET MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: The problem is, this doesn't add client-side validation. So if you are already using client-side validation based on attributes, this causes an inconsistent user experience. MS got it all wrong tying validation to attributes.

Comment: You are right. This doesn't add client-side validation. If you need it I believe the best way would be to write your own script to add this validation.

Answer (score 5):

Custom **Attribute**:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomRequiredIfAttribute : CustomAttribute
{
    private RequiredAttribute innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
    public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
    public object TargetValue { get; set; }

    public CustomRequiredIfAttribute()
    {
    }

    public CustomRequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
        : base()
    {
        this.DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
        this.TargetValue = targetValue;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return innerAttribute.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

Custom **RequiredIfValidator**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Custom.Web.Validation
{
    public class RequiredIfValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<CustomRequiredIfAttribute>
    {
        public RequiredIfValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, CustomRequiredIfAttribute attribute)
            : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            return base.GetClientValidationRules();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
        {
            // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
            var field = Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(Attribute.DependentProperty);

            if (field != null)
            {
                // get the value of the dependent property
                object value = field.GetValue(container, null);

                // compare the value against the target value
                if (this.IsEqual(value) || (value == null && Attribute.TargetValue == null))
                {
                    // match => means we should try validating this field
                    if (!Attribute.IsValid(Metadata.Model))
                    {
                        // validation failed - return an error
                        yield return new ModelValidationResult { Message = ErrorMessage };
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsEqual(object dependentPropertyValue)
        {
            bool isEqual = false;

            if (Attribute.TargetValue != null && Attribute.TargetValue.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                foreach (object o in (Array)Attribute.TargetValue)
                {
                    isEqual = o.Equals(dependentPropertyValue);
                    if (isEqual)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isEqual = Attribute.TargetValue.Equals(dependentPropertyValue);
            }

            return isEqual;
        }
    }
}
```

Register custom DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CustomRequiredIfAttribute), typeof(RequiredIfValidator));
```

Use this *CustomRequiredIf* in the **ViewModel**

```
[CustomRequiredIf("CategoryId", 3, ErrorMessageResourceName = GlobalResourceLiterals.AccountGroup_Required)]
public string AccountGroup { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres the updated MVC 3 version of that blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx