# Delete existing validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to clean Validation

```
packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]:input').each(function () { addFieldValidation($(this)); });
```

I`m using this but is not working correct:

```
packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]:input').data('val','false');
```

Have you got any idea?

Comment: @Diego Because I using checkbox and when clicked is on true I have different TextBox but option hide() didtn`t help to fix this issue. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I assume you are talking about DataAnnotation validations, taken to the client-side. A validation pretty much complex like this that you are saying I wouldn't do it with DataAnnotation, instead I'd implement IValidatableObject like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109277/asp-net-mvc-3-data-annotation-add-validation-dynamically

Comment: Of course, you will lose the validation logic in the client side.

Comment: @Diego I can`t change type of validation because I can`t change logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a JQuery expert, but I think you're calling that function incorrectly. According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/, you need to specify the element, the property, and the value as arguments, not just the latter two.

You should use the `attr` function for this:
`packageDiv.find('[name$=Code]:input').attr('value','false');`

Comment: Thanks for idea but didn`t fix this problem.

Comment: It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/DvKhq/ Bear in mind it just sets it to false. That doesn't make checkboxes or radio buttons turn off.